# post-receive hook cannot execute some commands if I push changes from local machine

Tags: linux, git, ssh, githooks

I have a problem with `post-receive` hook. The hook's task is to deploy just received code to webserver directory and send only latest commit message to PHP script.
Hook's code (in bare repo at server machine):

```
#!/bin/sh

# prod dir
TARGET="/var/www/html/repo"

# temp dir
TEMP="/srv/tmp/repo"

# git repo
REPO="/srv/git/repo.git"

mkdir -p $TEMP
git --work-tree=$TEMP --git-dir=$REPO checkout -f

cd $TEMP

cd /
rm -rf $TARGET
mv $TEMP $TARGET

cd $REPO
read oldrev newrev _branch
tail=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:'%s%b' $newrev)
curl -G 'http://example.com/phpscript.php' -d "msg=$tail"
```

There are two machines in local network:

- "server" machine with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS;
- local machine Windows 10, using "git-bash" to manage repository

#### "server" machine (Ubuntu)

There is a bare repo configured in `/srv/git/repo.git` directory AND that repo cloned into `/home/bob/projects/repo`. Group `gitusers` owns `/srv/git` directory and has rwx permissions. `bob` also is member of `gitusers` group.

While I push changes from local repo on this machine, there is no problem. Hook is executing, pushed code is deployed to webserver, php script is called, latest commit message added to DB. Fine.

Problem is with local machine with Windows.

#### local machine (Windows)

There is a `repo` cloned via SSH. I SSH'ed as `bob` who is member of `gitusers` and have permissions. (The fact `bob` wasn't member of `gitusers` was my earlier problem with SSH connection). Also remote is added as `ssh://bob@servermachineip/srv/git/repo.git`.

And at this moment I get a following error (I've pushed sample changes):

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 474 bytes | 474.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: mkdir: cannot create directory '/srv/tmp/repo': Permission denied
remote: fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
remote: hooks/post-receive: 15: cd: can't cd to /srv/tmp/repo
remote: rm: cannot remove '/var/www/html/repo/index.html': Permission denied
remote: mv: cannot stat '/srv/tmp/repo': No such file or directory
remote:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
remote:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
remote: 100    19    0    19    0     0    106      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   106
remote: Logged to remote db
To ssh://servermachineip/srv/git/repo.git
   24d56db..ab886dd  master -> master
```

So it seems hook for some reason cannot execute commands while executed remotely via ssh? I don't know how to solve this problem. Searched two days for answer, tried with settings permissions but I guess I definitely miss some details :/

Also, hook cannot execute linux commands like mkdir, rm or move, but it executes curl command and latest commit message is sent to DB properly :O

How can I solve given problem?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

**`/srv` permissions**

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 4 root users 4096 lis 21 23:33 git
drwxr-xr-x 2 root users 4096 lis 22 23:31 tmp
```

**`/srv/tmp` exists but is empty**

```
total 0
```

**`/var/www/html/repo` permissions**

```
total 1780
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 lis 22 23:31 assets
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     702 lis 22 23:31 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 lis 22 23:31 js
```

Comment: Show us the permissions (via `ls -l`) on `/srv` (and if it exists, `/srv/tmp`), as well as `/var/www/html/repo`.

Comment: @bk2204 sure, edited Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user `bob` doesn't have permissions to create directories in `/srv/tmp` and probably doesn't have permissions to delete files in `/var/www/html/repo`.

In order to create a directory or delete files in a directory, a user must have the write permission on the directory.  In this case, only `root` has permission to create directories in `/srv/tmp` because only `root` has permissions to write to that directory.  Assuming `bob` is part of the `users` group, you could run `chmod g+w /srv/tmp` which would all them to create directories.  Alternatively, you could use `/tmp` for this purpose, since all users will have permissions to write there.

For `/var/www/html/repo`, you'll likely need to do a `chgrp -R users /var/www/html/repo` and then set write permissions on each directory recursively.